# Add a DIV layer on left top of each hyperlink in page using CSS & PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to add a DIV layer (scrolling according to the position of hyperlink) just like the tooltip of hyperlink, but it shows when page loads, on left top of each hyperlink in a PHP-generated HTML link using CSS & PHP.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: make hyperlink tooltip stay appear next to all hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6WQyq/2/).